# Error in XML creation from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, windows

I have to create xml after reading from a datatable, in C# application. This logic is working fine except for “**’**” and “**&**”. When these special characters are encountered, there happened error in generated xml. The error is “Required white space was missing”

What are the changes to be made for the following code to make it working for the above mentioned special characters?

**Framework**: .Net 3.0

Note: The code given below explains what all are valid characters and what are invalid (special character).

Note: The datatable is read from a csv file which looks like

```
ZipCode,City,State,County
92357,VETRANS' HOSPITAL,CA,SAN BERDINO
36675,MOBLE P&DC,AL,MOBLE
```

Code folllows....

```
StringBuilder xmlForCSV = new StringBuilder();
        xmlForCSV.Append("<root>");
        foreach (DataRow excelRow in dtCSVExcelSource.Rows)
        {
            string zipCode = RemoveSpecialCharacters(excelRow["ZipCode"].ToString());
            string city = RemoveSpecialCharacters(excelRow["City"].ToString());
            string state = RemoveSpecialCharacters(excelRow["State"].ToString());
            string county = RemoveSpecialCharacters(excelRow["County"].ToString());

            xmlForCSV.Append("<row ZipCode='" + zipCode +
                                  "' City='" + city +
                                   "' State='" + state +
                                   "' County='" + county + "'/>");

        }
        xmlForCSV.Append("</root>");
```

The function is

```
private string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'z' || (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '_' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '(' || str[i] == ')' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '\\' || str[i] == '\'' || str[i] == '#')))
            {
                sb.Append(str[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (str[i] == '&')
                {
                    string ampersand = System.Convert.ToString(str[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    string specialCharacter = System.Convert.ToString(str[i]);
                }
            }



        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: Updated the post with sample csv file content from whcih the xml is generated.

Comment: Code seems fine.Did you google for that particular error ?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the single quote `'` to surround your attributes. Your `RemoveSpecialCharacters` function does not remove that therefor the XML you create is invalid:

```
<row ... City='VETRANS' HOSPITAL' ... />
```

is causing the trouble.

A quick fix is to disallow the single quote in `RemoveSpecialCharacters`.

For ways to automatically escape special characters look [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx).

In general though you should not be writing XML using a `StringBuilder`. Use something like `XmlTextWriter` or `XDocument` or even `dtCSVExcelSource.WriteXml(...)`.

BTW: Your `RemoveSpecialCharacters` function has lots of issues.

- The code in the `else` block does not do anything
- The parenthesis that starts before `str[i] >= 'A'` does not seem properly balanced
- Allowing the range `str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'z'` is unusual and allows characters like: `[\]^_`

Comment: Solved using WriteXml of datatable